# How to Increment IntegerField on django on button click from template?

Tags: django

How to Increment IntegerField on django on button click from template?
I have two buttons on template one for like and other for dislike.I am using different post requests for both of them but get no increase on likes and dislikes.
I hope Information is complete.

Here is the models.py code

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        Title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
        Meta_Tags = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        Description=models.TextField()
        Category=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        Body=RichTextUploadingField()
        Date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)   
        Views=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
        Likes=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
        Dis_Likes=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.Title + " | " + str(self.Date)
```

here is the view.py code

```
    def blogdetail(request,slug):
        post=Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
        post.Views +=1
        if request.POST.get('Like'):
            post.Likes +=1
        if request.POST.get('DisLike'):
            post.Dis_Likes +=1   
        post.save()
        context={
            'post':post
        }
        return render(request,'blogdetail.html',context)
```

template code is here

```
            <div class="submit-reaction p-3 mb-5">
            <span class="p-x3 mb-5" style="float:left">
            <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button  type="submit" name="Like"style="border:none;background:none;"><i 
            class="far fa-3x fa-thumbs-up text-secondary"></i></button>
            </form>
            </span>
            <span class="p-x3 mb-5" style="float:right">
            <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" name="DisLike"style="border:none;background:none;"> 
           <i class="far fa-3x fa-thumbs-down text-secondary"></i></button>
            </form>
            </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Well, Guy Just Solved my problem.   if 'Like' in request.POST:
      post.Likes +=1
if 'DisLike' in request.POST:
      post.Dis_Likes +=1

Comment: Hello @ZPro you can add it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Like` in your template is through form submit button not from form input value

So change like this.

```
if 'Like' in request.POST:
    post.Likes +=1
    post.save()
```

Comment: How to make an increment button, without needing to refresh the page to get the updated value?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `F()` expression for it

```
from django.db.models import F

reporter = Reporters.objects.get(name='Tintin')
reporter.stories_filed = F('stories_filed') + 1
reporter.save()
```

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: I think I'm having issue with my JavaScript. Because I need to reload the page to see that it incremented.